# how can I use a Microsoft Account to authenticate to my website

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a website where a users identity is needed,  I'd really prefer not to make them create yet another username/password combo that they have to remember

are there SDK's for allowing authentication from an Microsoft account?

Comment: I'm really hoping for a sample website

Comment: lol they've had so many names for this thing I'm sure it's hard to track down.  They used to charge a certain amount per year for sites to use it, and it wasn't very affordable for us little guys.  I wonder if it's free now with the rise of facebook, etc.

Answer (score 3):

That's rather easy as a default empty template of an ASP.NET 4.5 website shows how to have OAuth2 authentication with google/facebook/liveid/twitter.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's not clear to me what a user looks like once authed,  I need something unique to use for indexing it to my database (as a unique user name).  this value cant change over time, can I assume the combination of auth source and email is unique?

Comment: Yes, it is. If the identity provider returns an email, you can use it internally to distinguish users. I even don't think that you need to combine it with the auth source - this is because all reliable identity providers validate emails first before returning it. It means that if google/facebook/liveid say that user's email is foo@bar.qux then you can trust this regardless of what the auth source was among these three.

Comment: @Tymski: it is, the answer is from 2013 and this default template has been replaced with Identity subsystem some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Principal Context class. You can create it using a localhost (Machine) or domain context and use the ValidateCrentials(string username, string password) method to authenticate using Windows credentials.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx

Here's how I've used it in my website. (Put this in a POST method of your authentication controller or something)

The code below will take a username say "bob" or "localhost\bob" or "DOMAIN\bob" etc., and get the right PrincipalContext for authenticating the user. NOTE: it's case insensitive here.

```
        public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, System.Security.SecureString password)
    {
        string domain = Environment.MachineName;
        if (username.Contains("\\"))
        {
            domain = username.Split('\\')[0];
            username = username.Split('\\')[1];
        }

        if (domain.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            domain = Environment.MachineName;

        if (domain.Equals(Environment.MachineName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
            {
                return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password.ToUnsecureString());
            }
        else
            using(PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                //return context.ValidateCredentials(domain + "\\" + username, password.ToUnsecureString());
                return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password.ToUnsecureString());
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides the [Live Connect SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/ff621314.aspx) for integration Microsoft services into your applications, including the Microsoft Accounts identity provider.

There is a specific example on [Server-Side Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx) which should cover all you need to get integrated.

Comment: They both redirect to `Shared controls for OneDrive integration` :( why is Microsoft's preservation of links so terrible

Comment: It's fascinating how much this topic has changed in the last 5 years. The Live Connect SDK will be unavailable by November 2018. The information I linked to is so redundant that it may be better they no longer go anywhere useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean from an active directory windows account? If so you could use windows authentication and just have the index page sign them in automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Use the following commands in your code behind file to get the relevant information for signing in:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
User.Identity.AuthenticationType
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of changes / rebranding / deprecation / dead links from Microsoft drives me crazy. In any case, the latest version of this from what I've found is "Microsoft Account external login", which can be first set up on the [Microsoft Developer Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).

I found a guide that explains how to do this for .Net Core at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins, though the first half (e.g. setting the Redirect URI) isn't framework-specific.

I also found some relevant source code for .Net Core at https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/MicrosoftAccountOptions.cs, which shows some of the Claims (user details) that are retrieved:

```
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "displayName");
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "givenName");
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "surname");
ClaimActions.MapCustomJson(ClaimTypes.Email,
    user => user.Value<string>("mail") ?? user.Value<string>("userPrincipalName"));
```

The support from the latest version of .Net Core suggests to me that this external login API still works. I haven't tested them out yet, I will update if I get to do this login integration.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use "Live Connect" via Oauth 2.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

or

https://dev.onedrive.com/

Comment: First link is dead, couldn't find anything via the second